# Difference in performance of adding elements in Treeset directly vs transferring from arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, treeset

I want to know the difference in performance between adding element in a TreeSet one by one versus adding elements in ArrayList and then transferring to TreesSet by .addAll() method. I know TreeSet uses Red–black tree as its data structure. Just want to know the basic internal workings of this two process. Which one of the following will be faster and why?

```
    TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<Integer>();   
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        ts.add(sc.nextInt());
```

OR,

```
   TreeSet<Integer> ts = new TreeSet<Integer>();    
   ArrayList<Integer> ar = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            ts.add(sc.nextInt());

            ts.addAll(ar);
```

Here sc is an object of Scanner class(it may be anything else as well). Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TreeSet.addAll(c)` method does the optimization only if the `c` is an instance of `SortedSet`. In other cases it just iterates over the collection and adds elements one by one.

Therefore, it does not make any sense to put elements into `ArrayList` first and then use `TreeSet.addAll(list)` method. You will get worse performance and higher memory consumption.

From the big-O perspective, both solutions have `n*log(n)` complexity.

EDIT. TreeSet has 2 important properties: Elements are unique and they are sorted. If you are only interested in the unique-elements property, using a HashSet would give you a complexity of `n`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought the re-ordering of the nodes in TreeSet will be different in the two different operations above.

Comment: @Nitin Dandriyal: n inserts each taking log(n) - for me it sounds like n*log(n).

Answer (score 0):

Only in case the `Collection` being passed to `addAll(Collection)` is `instanceof SortedSet` and `instanceof TreeMap` the tree creation time is linear.

In your second case creating an `ArrayList` takes extra time. Rest being same since `TreeSet#addAll` internally calls `Collection#add()` in `for` loop

So, its better to call `add` then `addAll` if the Collection already is not available

Comment: Hi Nitin, thanks for the answer, but the addAll() method is outside the for-loop.

Comment: I know `addAll` is outside `for` loop in your code, I am mentioning the `for` loop used in `addAll` method of the `java.util.TreeSet` in case `Collection` is not an `instanceof SortedSet and TreeMap`